# How to count straight cells in a table

Tags: vba

Im working with a spreadsheet which I can't format the way I think it would be easier so I'm tryng to work around.

There's a table with the Employee names and the weekdays which I have to leave it blank if he is not working that day or fill in with his specific shift time. Basically, I want to display a message if the employee will work more than 4 days straight or if he has more than 48h already assigned on that week.

I can manage to display the message if the hours are above 48, but I can't manage the 4 days straight. I tried using FOR to go all over the cells but I can't formulate a counter.

I'm pretty sure there's an easier solution for that, better than using FOR but my knowledge on this is quite low.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQD3T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array formula to show the longest streak of consecutive days.

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(B2:H2)>0,COLUMN(B2:H2)),IF(LEN(B2:H2)>0,0,COLUMN(B2:H2))))
```

Enter that with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter. You can compare the result of that formula to "4" and if it's greater, do whatever you want.

If you can't (or don't want to) add a formula, here's a VBA function that does the same thing.

```
Public Function MaxConsecutiveDays(ByRef rRng As Range) As Long
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim lMax As Long
        
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Then
            lCnt = 0
        Else
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
        End If
        
        If lCnt > lMax Then
            lMax = lCnt
        End If
    Next rCell
    
    MaxConsecutiveDays = lMax
    
End Function
```

Then you can use that in your code like

```
Public Sub test()

    If MaxConsecutiveDays(Sheet1.Range("B2:H2")) > 4 Then
        Err.Raise 9999, , "Too many days"
    Else
        MsgBox "OK"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

All of this assumes that you if there is anything in a cell, it's 8 hours and that you don't have to concern yourself with parsing the hours string in the cell to determine how long they're scheduled for.